# Couldn't upgrade my custom module "Events" - Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I am new to python and not sure how to fix this error. Please guide me. I want to upgrade my custom module called "Events" however I couldn't upgrade the module due to the below error. The reason I want to upgrade my module is to make my module name visible when I click the box menu top left corner. Please help me to solve this error.

I get the following error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\func.py", line 71, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\lru.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj]
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x000001FCB3A6A378>, 'events.model_events_events')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 564, in _tag_record
    f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 660, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 666, in model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 1927, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-35>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\cache.py", line 90, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 1920, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: events.model_events_events

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 912, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1393, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1381, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\api.py", line 396, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-77>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 654, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 593, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 451, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 348, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 221, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 69, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 733, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 799, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 719, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 685, in _tag_root
    )) from e
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo14\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/c:/virtual_odoo14/scripts/odoo/addons/events/views/events.xml:121, near
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="events_action_server">
            <field name="name">events server</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_events_events"/>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
                   action = {
                "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
                "view_mode": "kanban,calendar,tree,form,pivot,graph",
                "res_model": events_details,
            }
            </field>
        </record>
```

Here's the events.xml code:

```
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="view_events_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">events.form</field>
            <field name="model">events_details</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Events" create="0" write="0" js_class="events_form">
                    <sheet>
                    <field name="image_1920" widget='image' class="oe_avatar" options='{"zoom": true, "preview_image":"image_128"}'/>
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                        <h1>
                            <field name="name" placeholder="Events's Name" required="True"/>
                        </h1>
                        <h2>
                            <field name="description" placeholder="Event's Description"/>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="event_type"/>
                            <field name="start_at"/>
                            <field name="created_at"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="status"/>
                            <field name="end_at"/>
                            <field name="updated_at"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="view_events_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">events.tree</field>
            <field name="model">events_details</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Events">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="description"/>
                    <field name="event_type"/>
                    <field name="status"/>
                    <field name="start_at"/>
                    <field name="end_at"/>
                    <field name="created_at"/>
                    <field name="updated_at"/>
                    <field name="thumbnail_url"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="view_events_kanban_menu" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">events.kanban</field>
            <field name="model">events_details</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <kanban>
                    <templates>
                    <t t-name="kanban-box">
                        <div class="oe_resource_vignette">
                            <div class="oe_resource_image">
                                <a type="edit"><img t-att-src="kanban_image('object.name', ,photo')" class="oe_resource_picture"/></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="oe_resource_details">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><field name="name"/></li>
                                    <li><field name="event_type"/></li>
                                    <li><field name="status"/></li>
                                    <li><field name="start_at"/></li>
                                    <li><field name="end_at"/></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                    </templates>
                </kanban>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="view_events_search" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">events.search</field>
            <field name="model">events_details</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search>
                    <field name="name"/>
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="events_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Events</field>
            <field name="res_model">events_details</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
<!--            <field name="view_type">form</field>-->
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form,search,kanban</field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_view_events_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
            <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_events_form"/>
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="events_action"/>
        </record>

        <record id="action_view_events_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
            <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
            <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_events_tree"/>
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="events_action"/>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_event_view">
            <field name="name">Events</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">events_details</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,calendar,tree,form,pivot,graph</field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.server" id="events_action_server">
            <field name="name">events server</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_events_events"/>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
                   action = {
                "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
                "view_mode": "kanban,calendar,tree,form,pivot,graph",
                "res_model": events_details,
            }
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem name="Events" id="menu_events" parent="menu_root" sequence="10" action="events_action_server"/>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

Here's the models.py code:

```
import base64
from werkzeug.urls import url_encode

from datetime import datetime
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
from odoo.modules.module import get_module_resource



class Events(models.Model):
    _name = 'events_details'
    _description = 'Events Details'

    name = fields.Char(string="Event Name", size=200, required=True, index=True)
    description = fields.Text(string="Description")
    event_type = fields.Integer(string="Event Type", required=True)
    status = fields.Integer(string="Status", required=True)
    start_at = fields.Datetime('Start_at', help='Event Start Date & Time', required=True)
    end_at = fields.Datetime('End_at', help='Event End Date & Time', required=True)
    created_at = fields.Datetime('Created_at', help='Event Create Date & Time', default=fields.Datetime.now)
    updated_at = fields.Datetime('Updated_at', help='Event Update Date & Time')
    thumbnail_url = fields.Char(string="Thumbnail URL", size=500, help='Event Image URL')

    @api.model
    def _default_image(self):
        image_path = get_module_resource('events', 'img', 'default_image.png')
        return base64.b64encode(open(image_path, 'rb').read())

    image_1920 = fields.Image(default=_default_image)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        """Method Override for allocate leaves to the employee."""
        if vals.get('id'):
            user = self.env['events_details'].browse(vals['id'])
            vals.update(self._sync_user(user, vals.get('image_1920') == self._default_image()))
            vals['name'] = vals.get('name', user.name)
        events = super(Events, self).create(vals)
        url = '/web#%s' % url_encode({
            'active_id': events.id,
            'active_model': 'events_details',
        })
        events_allocations = self.env['events_details']
        for events_allocation in events_allocations:
            events_dict = {
                'name': events_allocation.name,
                'description': events_allocation.description,
                'event_type': events_allocation.event_type,
                'status': events_allocation.status,
                'start_at': events_allocation.start_at,
                'end_at': events_allocation.end_at,
                'created_at': events_allocation.created_at,
                'updated_at': events_allocation.updated_at,
                'thumbnail_url': url,
            }
            new_allocation = self.env['events_details'].create(events_dict)
            new_allocation.sudo().action_approve()
        return events
```

Comment: Try to correct the indentation of the server action code (remove the leading spaces).

Comment: Hi Kenly. I correct the indentation of the server action code by removing the leading spaces like this [<field name="name">events_server</field>] and tried to upgrade the module however fail to upgrade the module.

Comment: I get this error 'ValueError: External ID not found in the system: events.model_events_events'.

Comment: Where did you define the `events_events` model?